# htaccess multidomain with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, alias

I want migrate Website on wordpress from old web  hosting to new web hosting.

My new hosting provider allows extra domain (alias) like this

```
www/domains/domain1.com

www/domains/domain2.com
```

My root directory on the new hosting:

```
/

-.htaccess

-session

-tmp

-www/domains/my-domain.com/wordpressfolder
```

I have problem with error when I used internal web address(myinternaladdress.hosting.com) from my new hosting to test if everthing work before I route my domain to new hosting.

In Wordpress I set wp-config.php WP_HOME,WP_SITEURL,WP_HOME,WP_SITEURL to

"myinternaladdress.hosting.com/www/domains/my-domain.com/"

.htaccess file in www directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domains/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) domains/%2/$1 [DPI]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdom/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdom/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdom/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) subdom/%2/$1 [DPI]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^domains/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^subdom/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]
```

.htaccess file in Wordpress directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I go to myinternaladdress.hosting.com/www/domains/my-domain.com/ main page work well but e.g. /my-domain.com/about/ not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to ***`Settings > Permalinks`*** in the admin dashboard and save the page settings and that will flush the rewrite rules which should allow your pages to be accessed again.

Comment: I can't access to admin dashboard, I have some internal server error.

Comment: I don't know why, now admin dashboard work and I flushed rule for permalinks in setting. Now everthing work thanks.